# Custom HTML Module - does not support joomla 3.0

Tags: html, joomla, module

I am using advanced version of joomla, but facing problems when I am using custom html module or using HTML for articles too. The all attributes in HTML are replased by the / and "

Here's what is happening:
0. To start with, all the images were displaying as per the install just fine.

1. Copied the default module "Image Module", with a new name of "Image Module Me"
2. Set the menus so that the original module displays in the default menu, and the new one in my test menu
3. Somewhere along the line the images stoped displaying properly (showing a broken image link) for both the default Image Module and my copy.
4. When I look at the image module, I can see that the html has been changed.
5. Reset the html by reinserting the image, which generates the following html:

   img src="images/headers/walden-pond.jpg"

   - note that the image appears just fine in the admin editor at this point
6. Save the module
7. Click on custom output - an lo and behold I've got a broken image link. When I check out the html I can see the following:

   img src="\"images/headers/walden-pond.jpg\""

**EDIT1 :**

This is just because of Magic_quotes. How to disable magic quotes in joomla 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

To disable magic quotes you have to edit the php.ini file in your server. In all honesty I'm surprised you could even install Joomla 3.0 as its a requirement for Joomla 3.0 that magic quotes is disabled. If you can edit the php.ini file you must add in:

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

You may need to contact your host to do this. In a last resort (and only in a last resort) edit your .htaccess file something along the lines of:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

etc.

Comment: try to use adding this line in your php.ini magic_quotes_gpc = Off and restart your apache server. but this require at installation of joomla. when i m trying to install joomla 3.0 this happen with me at installation time i can't install joomla without off this